# Flutter - Binding flutter instance with native instance

Tags: flutter

I am familiar with both pigeon and Methodcalls. I have developed a basic Flutter plugin to invoke native functions. However, I am facing an issue binding the Dart instance to the native instance.

Here's the native side implementation:

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
        channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), "xyz/Flutter");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);

        pigeon.setUp(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), this);
        
    }
```

now on the Dart side

```
final _instance1 = TestFlutter();
final _instance2 = TestFlutter();

_instance1.setup("abc");
_instance2.setup("abcd");
```

For every instance on the Dart side, I need to create a native class instance and then call the native methods on that instance.

I was assuming that `onAttachedToEngine` would be called twice (once for each instance). If that was the case, I could have created two instances there. But it is not the case and it is only called once.

I have referred to https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels, but it doesn't describe handling multiple instances.

This seems like a basic requirement, so I believe I might be overlooking something here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: on dart side, when calling `MethodChannel` ctor, did you try to add a unique `BinaryMessenger`? just a guess, never tested ...

Comment: Pigeon-generated code uses the same Messenger. Is there a way to modify how pigeon generates code?

Comment: never used that bird, did you try, just for testing, to do that the good, old way? without any package generated code?

Comment: I can certainly try and post results. However, we have a large native library that also updates frequently so Pigeon looks like a fast way to generate the code for all the platforms.

Comment: If multiple messengers work you could a) fix the pigeon code (if it's open source) b) ask the authors to do that, if multiple messengers don't work then...  well...

Comment: thanks, I started looking at that option but then came across another limitation of pigeon it does not support returning an object with methods. I will use methodcall and post results later here